# ALAssetsGroup becomes invalid

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I'm using `AssetsLibrary` framework for saving assets to a specific album (`ALAssetsGroup`).

Since I'm using the `ALAssetsGroup` (for the album where I want to save the assets) quite often, I figured it would be wise to retain it, so I don't have to iterate (asynchronously) through the groups each time I need it.

When retrieving/creating the album everything shows up correctly (for `valueForProperty:`), but the group seems to invalidate itself after some time, and all its properties will return `nil`. Also, `addAsset:` won't work on it, so I have to search for the album again (this time it's searched by its URL, but it's still asynchronous).

Is there a way around this (to keep the `ALAssetsGroup` valid)?

This is happening on iOS 5, and the library (`ALAssetsLibrary`) is retained as well.
I am using a setter to make sure that I don't reset the `group` myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an observer for the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification for your ALAssetsLibrary and upon receiving it re-query for any of your cached AL* objects. That will be posted immediately before the vended AL* objects become invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I just remembered that I had a similar issue a while back and had to reload all assets each time a change occurred. Hopefully they'll create a better system in the future.

Comment: WOW. WOW. WOW. This answer saved me from such a headache of a problem. I was trying to save multiple photos in a loop to the assets library when all of a sudden the group returned from groupFromURL function would become invalid. It was not nil, it would just lose all of it's properties as the OP described. I never saw in the documentation anything that indicated this would happen to the object being passed to the completion block, THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: but aren't notifications asynchronous? Therefore, couldn't we still be using the AL* objects before we process the notification?